# How to use fixed point decimals in emacs lisp?

Tags: numbers

How to use large decimal numbers with fixed precision, like money amount, in emacs lisp? For example, I'm writing a function that takes amount of money as a parameter. When I pass large float like 999999999999999.01 it looses precision and becomes 999999999999999.0. I didn't find fixed type in manual. My workarounds are:

1. Pass two integers separately, integer part and fraction part - like dollars and cents
2. Pass amount as string and parse it to two integers,

but both of this approaches will be less convenient for users.

Comment: You could use a single integer and then divide it by your fixed number whenever you need to display it. From what I recall, elisp lacks proper bit shifting, so "proper" fixed point numbers can only be approximated with multiplication and division.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the fractional representation of numbers from [calc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/).

I am not sure why you think that passing the amount as string is inconvenient for the user.

I would pass that input to `calc` and adapt the precision to the length of the string.

Example:

```el
(calc-frac-mode 1)
(setq str "999999999999999.01")
(setq var-x (calc-eval (list (format "pfrac(%s)" str) 'calc-internal-prec (length str)) 'raw))
(setq var-y (calc-eval "pfrac(1.01)" 'raw))
(setq var-z (math-add var-x var-y))
(calc-eval (list "pfloat($)" 'calc-internal-prec (calc-eval "floor(log10(abs($))+3)" 'raw var-z)) nil var-z)
```

The result of that elisp segment is `1000000000000000.02`.